# php form stay on page with div showing close form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have the following form that works except for the success message staying on the same page.

I keep racking my brain, but at this point it is mush.

**Problem
I need to have the form close and show the 'success' DIV when the form is submitted.

Right now the only thing I can do is get it to go to a thanks.php page by using a header.

all the code is here at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/webs4me/hyArd/1/

except the send.hello.php which is below: - Thanks

```
   <?php
   // Clean up the input values
   foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
     if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
       $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]);

     $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
   }

   // Honeypot don't send - THIS WILL BE HIDDEN LATER
   if(!empty($_POST["confirm_email"])) {
   header("location:spam.php");exit;
   }

   // Assign the input values to variables for easy reference
   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $email = $_POST["email"];
   $confirm = $_POST["confirm_email"];
   $phone = $_POST["phone"];
   $message = $_POST["message"];

   // Send the email *********** enter your email address and message info 
   $to = "myemail@myemail.com"; 
   $subject = "Website message: $name";
   $message = "From:\n$name\n\nEmail:\n$email\n\nPhone:\n$phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
   $headers = "From: $email";

   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

   header('location: thanks.php');


   ?>
```

Comment: You don't want to reload the page with the form? then you need ajax

Comment: do you have a suggestion code for AJAX. I have been looking.

Comment: I also did not know if there was a way to echo the response and die/exit the form showing the div. kind of a hide/show onlclick but onsubmit instead

Comment: Also your `#success{display:none}` is never changing the display, and.. what should `thanks.php` display?

Comment: @porfiriopartida I only had the display to hide the remarks. The thanks.php is just text that says, Thanks for your message!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using JQuery, use `$.POST`:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
});
```

- `data` would be constructed from the values of all the form's inputs.
- `url` would be the `hello.php` page
- You'd add either an `onsubmit` function to the form, or take out the submit button and add a regular input button with an `onclick` call to a function that builds `data` and calls $.POST

Comment: @webs4me It does work, but you're probably missing a few pieces. 1. You need a "success" function that handles what to do on success, 2. Your "hello.php" page needs to output something that tells of success or failure (prferably a JSON object), 3. You need to set "dataType". Please read the JQuery url I provided, and see this example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp I am sorry, but I will not write all the code for you. You need to do some learning and adapt the code to your situation so you can "learn to fish."

Comment: @porfiriopartida if you're using Ajax, you no longer need to redirect, so there is no thanks.php anymore.

Comment: @Don Im not using a database. Just PHP Server

Comment: @Don thanks. i am not asking you to write it for me, but a good explaination would help someone learn to catch the fish. you left out the database which is why i did not understand it. i am not using a database. thanks for sending the link. i understand what you were trying to achieve by your answer.

Comment: @webs4me Don's code should be placed in a submit call of the form, url should be send.hello.php and data (you must see the doc) could be a serialized form, then you have to call a function on success (see ajax doc) and there you will call the unhide success...

Comment: If you use ajax then there is no point in this case to call spam or thanks.php that's true, that's why I asked what about thanks.php we don't know if his code has to do something there (most likely not). Then he could change it for a response status but we don't know that, we only know that he wants to call a thanks.php and render its message?